# Removing all div tags from HTML string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to strip all divs.

Input:

```
<p>111</p>

<div class="1334">bla</div>

<p>333</p>

<p>333</p>

<div some unkown stuff>bla2</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
   <p>111</p>

    <p>333</p>

    <p>333</p>
```

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
release_content = re.sub("/<div>.*<\/div>/s", "", release_content)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Do not use regex for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1253312). Use an html parser. Here is a solution in python with BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
[div.extract() for div in soup.findAll('div')]

with open('Path/to/file.modified', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: That's funny because I am actually using BeautifulSoup and decided to use regex because I thought it's not doable with BeautifulSoup :)

Comment: This does not work. Line soup = BeautifulSoup(content) give error:TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. So it should be fixed somehow

Comment: Fixed: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser').

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any delimeters for regexp patterns in python:

```
release_content = re.sub("<div>.*<\/div>", "", release_content)
```

Are you sure the `div`s won't have any attributes? What happens to nested `div`s?

Comment: If it is anything but the simplest case, do not use regexps.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a *greedy* operator: `*`. It will try to match as much as possible before it stops. You can try using the non-greedy version, `*?`. So long as you don't have nested `<div>` tags you will be OK.

```
release_content = re.sub("(?s)<div>.*?<\/div>", "", release_content)
```

If you can have nested `<div>` tags, then you'll want to use an HTML library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Per your edit, to account for attributes you can simply amend the leading `<div>` of the pattern:

```
release_content = re.sub("(?s)<div(?: [^>]*)?>.*?<\/div>", "", release_content)
```